# How to make everyother word in string upper

Tags: javascript, string

I don't understand why when I return `element.toUpperCase()`
it doesn't return it back to the array as uppercase, however if I `console.log(element.toUpperCase())` before that return statement it displays as upper case

```
const sentence = "fur pillows are hard to actually sleep on";

const uppercaseOddWords = (string) => {
  string = string.split(" ");
  oddWords = string.filter((element, index) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
      return element;
    }
    return element.toUpperCase();
  });
  console.log(oddWords.join(" "));
};

uppercaseOddWords(sentence);
```

Comment: Try replacing `.filter` with `.map`

Answer (score 3):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) callback expected to return `truthy` or `falsy` value, in your case all values with be `truthy` and will not `filter` anything, what you are looking for is [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) method.

```js
const sentence = "fur pillows are hard to actually sleep on";

const uppercaseOddWords = (string) => {
  string = string.split(" ");
  oddWords = string.map((element, index) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
      return element;
    }
    return element.toUpperCase();
  });
  console.log(oddWords.join(" "));
};

uppercaseOddWords(sentence);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.filter()` should only be used if you want to pick elements of the array and leave out something based on a boolean logic test. The function expects a logical condition, and can either return `true` or `false`. You are using the function wrong.

`.map()` on the other hand is used to transform the elements in the array from their original state to any other state based on the logic in the function.

```js
const sentence = "fur pillows are hard to actually sleep on";

const uppercaseOddWords = (string) => {
  const words = string.split(" ");
  const oddWords = words.map((word, index) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
      return word;
    }
    return word.toUpperCase();
  });
  console.log(oddWords.join(" "));
};

uppercaseOddWords(sentence);
```

Answer (score 0):

Still wondering why returning it doesn't work, but I got the function to work this way;

```
const sentence = "fur pillows are hard to actually sleep on";

const uppercaseOddWords = (string) => {
  let newString = "";
  string = string.split(" ");
  string.filter((element, index) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
      return (newString += element + " ");
    }
    return (newString += element.toUpperCase() + " ");
  });
  console.log(newString.trim()); //remove trailing spaces
};

uppercaseOddWords(sentence);
```

Comment: You can do it like this `data.filter((element, index) => { if (index % 2 != 0) { data[index] = element.toUpperCase() } return true; });`,see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method which will return same number of elements as passed, Based on the condition for odd elements, We can convert odd elements in an upper case.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const sentence = "fur pillows are hard to actually sleep on";

const uppercaseOddWords = (string) => {
  string = string.split(" ");
  const res = string.map((element, index) => (index % 2 === 0) ? element.toUpperCase() : element);
  console.log(res.join(" "));
};

uppercaseOddWords(sentence);
```